# How to use JQuery datepicker and timepicker together

Tags: javascript

I want to implement JQuery Datepicker and Time picker together. I downloaded the plugin.
And I use this JS to configure it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/timepicker-addon.js"></script>
....
                       <script type="text/javascript">
                            //For calendar
                            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                                inline: true,
                                showWeek: true,
                                firstDay: 1,
                                dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
                                timeFormat: 'h:m',
                            separator: ' @ '
                            });                            
                        </script>
```

But when I open the JSF page I see simple calendar. Can you help me to implement the timepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use what this article recommends: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

After using it, the following will be what you will see:

[image]