# How to use Timepicker and Datepicker together

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use JQuery datepicker and timepicker together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703255/how-to-use-jquery-datepicker-and-timepicker-together)

I want to integrate timepicker and datepicker together. Something like this:

[image]

Is it possible to use them together for one input field?

Comment: You just asked this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703255/how-to-use-jquery-datepicker-and-timepicker-together

Comment: Yes but this time it's different I want to use this http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ and this http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using jQuery's really nice plug-in [Datetimepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

It would be much easier and probably more efficient than integrating two different plug-ins together in a single field and getting a text result based on these.

Comment: came here to say this. its great, works much better than the standard datepicker too